# The click event of PlatformView does't work in the Flutter 3.x.x version

Tags: android, flutter

I want to add a click event to PlatformView, but it doesn't work. I tested it with a real Android device.

flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.0.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision cd41fdd495 (6 months ago) • 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
Engine • revision f15f824b57
Tools • Dart 2.17.3 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

The following code is written with reference to [the official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views?tab=android-platform-views-java-tab)

Dart code

```
class NativeDemoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NativeDemoWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String viewType = '<platform-view-type>';
    return PlatformViewLink(
      surfaceFactory: (context, controller) {
        return AndroidViewSurface(
          controller: controller as AndroidViewController,
          hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.opaque,
          gestureRecognizers: const <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
        );
      },
      onCreatePlatformView: (params) {
        return PlatformViewsService.initSurfaceAndroidView(
          id: params.id,
          viewType: viewType,
          layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          onFocus: () {
            params.onFocusChanged(true);
          },
        )
          ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
          ..create();
      },
      viewType: viewType,
    );
  }
}
```

Android code

NativeView.java

```
package com.example.native_demo_demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView;

public class NativeView implements PlatformView {

    @NonNull
    private final LinearLayout layout;

    NativeView(Context context, int id) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Rendered on a Android view(id: " + id + ")");

        layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 100, 255));

        layout.addView(textView);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

NativeViewFactory.java

```
public class NativeViewFactory extends PlatformViewFactory {
    public NativeViewFactory() {
        super(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PlatformView create(@Nullable Context context, int viewId, @Nullable Object args) {
        return new NativeView(context, viewId);
    }
}
```

NativeDemoDemoPlugin.java

```
public class NativeDemoDemoPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
    ...
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "native_demo_demo");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
        flutterPluginBinding.getPlatformViewRegistry().registerViewFactory(
                "<platform-view-type>", new NativeViewFactory()
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

The test code is as follows

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print('tap tap tap...'),
              child: const NativeDemoWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

When I click the red square in the screen, there is no log output. I don't know why there is no output log. Thanks!!!

Comment: I found a related answer on github：
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52002#issuecomment-763298565
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52002